# sqlite3 ERR DLOPEN FAILED version `GLIBC_2.29' not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, github

I started getting this error from nowhere
and I googled a lot but got no help

This was working fine but maybe after I setup github workflows `Codeql-analysis.yml`. or maybe after i updated packages - started getting this error.

- my app code is clean no issues.
- I'm sure my app code not made this error.

```json
    "sqlite": "^4.0.25",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
```

> sqlite3 5.0.3 is latest version

**Error:**

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/dreamy/YouTube/Silenzio_Bruno/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dreamy/YouTube/Silenzio_Bruno/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

Node.js v17.9.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

- versions

```json
npm: '8.7.0'
node: 'v17.9.0'
```

This what i tried till now as google solutions

- I removed .github/workflows folder.
- i created new folder copied all code files tried to run again.
- I tried removing `node_modulues` folder and `yarn.lock` file and tried installing again
- Tried to clean cache `yarn` and `git` with `npm cache clean sqlite3`, `yarn cache clean`, `git rm -r --cached .`
- tried `npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source`
- tried updating all packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me yesterday as well. After I updated my Debian system, if found Debian upgraded Bullseye to include GLIBC 2.31:

https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libc6-amd64

The SQLITE3 module page explains the module including statically linked, pre-built binaries that require specific versions of GLIBC:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3 (Section titled Prebuilt binaries)

Until the module gets updated itself, the same page describes compiling from source using the host system's sqlite3 install.

For Debian Bullseye I did the following:

```
apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
npm install --build-from-source --sqlite=/usr/bin sqlite3
```

The module worked after that. I don't know much about your environment and how easy this would be to implement for you. I suspect if you check the GLIBC version on the host system, you also recently had a change.

Comment: This working but should i have to use `npm install....` for every new project?